# Is the given hadith authentic?

Tags: hadith

I found this hadith in [wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Hidden_Treasure#:%7E:text=I%20was%20a%20hidden%20treasure%2C%20and%20I%20wished%20to%20be,known%3B%20then%20they%20knew%20Me) .

> *کنت کنزاً مخفیاً فأحببت أن أعرف فخلقت الخلق لکی أعرف*
>
> I was a hidden treasure, and I wished to be known, so I created a creation (mankind), then made Myself known to them, and they recognised Me.

What is the source of this hadith and is this hadith authentic(Saheeh).

Comment: This sounds very doubtful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This supposed hadith qudsi is often quoted by sufi's (for example al-Alusi quoted it in his tafssir of verse [51:56](https://quran.com/51/56) without reference) and also appears in shi'a books (for example Bihar al-Anwar of al-Majalisi) however none could share any fully connected narrator chain be it a sahih or da'if one.

Therefore it is rather safe to say that this <s>hadith</s> report is not authentic.
And it was never uttered by the prophet.
This is the view of scholars like az-Zarakshy, ibn Hajar, as-Suyuti and ibn Taymiyyah on this supposed narrative.

Comment: So what is the classification of this hadith. Is it Hasan, daif or murtad

Comment: @Blue a hadith that is not authentic can't be hassan, and I don't know what you mean by murtad. It is in best case very weak if not simply a fabrication.